# Selenium (python library) not able to upload using send_keys function

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
def sendpdf():
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.docdroid.net/')
    upload_box=driver.find_element_by_id('select')
    #upload_box.send_keys('C:\Users\User\Desktop\MySql.pdf')
    upload_box.send_keys(r'C://Users/User/Desktop/Mysql2.pdf')

sendpdf()
```

It opens the website(DocDroid.net) but does not upload the pdf I'm sending in through send_keys() function.
There isn't any error.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you are supposed to use `send_keys` on the `<input>`. It does not work the same way for a `<button>`

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you want to use `send_keys()` on the file `<input>`, not the `<button>`. If you navigate the DOM, you will find the input is hidden and has the following class `dz-hidden-input`.

The input element is.

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="dz-hidden-input" data-fillr-id="1634059288" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
```

The following code works. The reason I put a sleep is because I had to login or you will get a popup requesting you to login.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
def sendpdf():
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.docdroid.net/')
    time.sleep(30)
    upload_box=driver.find_element_by_class_name('dz-hidden-input')
    upload_box.send_keys(r'C://test.docx')
    time.sleep(30)

sendpdf()
```

Comment: How did you find [name('dz-hidden-input')]? plus I don't know what DOM means, please tell.

Comment: I found that by looking through the source of the page (similar to how you found the button), but searching for `<input>` with a type of `file`. The DOM is essentially the structure of the webpage. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Comment: def sendpdf():
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.docdroid.net/')
    upload_box=driver.find_element_by_id('select')
    #upload_box.send_keys('C:\Users\User\Desktop\MySql.pdf')
    upload_box=driver.find_element_by_class_name('dz-hidden-input')
    upload_box.send_keys(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\MySql.pdf')
    time.sleep(30)
    
sendpdf()

Comment: The code does work, I tested it. Can you post your error? Have you logged in before uploading the file? It requires you to be logged in.